# How to filter out nested objects in JSON array?

Tags: javascript

This is my JSON object array which contains nested objects :

```
var obj=   [
       {
          "ASIN":"BCXXXXX1",
          "VariationAttributes":[
             {
                "Name":"hand_orientation",
                "Value":"Left Hand"
             },
             {
                "Name":"shaft_material_type",
                "Value":"KBS Max 90 Steel"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "ASIN":"BCXXXXX2",
          "VariationAttributes":[
             {
                "Name":"hand_orientation",
                "Value":"Right Hand"
             },
             {
                "Name":"shaft_material_type",
                "Value":"KBS Max 90 Steel"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]

var curState=[
   {
      "Name":"hand_orientation",
      "Value":"Left Hand"
   },
   {
      "Name":"shaft_material_type",
      "Value":"KBS Max 90 Steel"
   }
]
```

Now I want to filter out items that have variationAattributes that match curState.

```
var result = obj.map(m=>m.VariationAttributes).filter(search, curState);


function search(item){
  return Object.keys(this).some((key) => item[key] === this[key]);
}
```

The result is blank. You can play with the code at https://playcode.io./518049

Comment: do you want to match all states? or match only 1 of the states?

Comment: I made you a snippet here instead. No need to go external for such examples

Comment: @Alex it should match all states. thanks.

Comment: First you should read about the `filter` definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to filter your `arr` based on the callback function. The callback function will return true if [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) name or value attribute from the current objects `VariationAttributes` property doesn't equal that of its corresponding object in the `curState` object like so:

```js
const arr = [{ "ASIN": "BCXXXXX1", "VariationAttributes": [{ "Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Left Hand" }, { "Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel" } ] }, { "ASIN": "BCXXXXX2", "VariationAttributes": [{ "Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Right Hand" }, { "Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel" } ] } ];
const curState = [{ "Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Left Hand" }, { "Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel" } ];

const res = arr.filter(
  obj => obj.VariationAttributes.some(({Name, Value}, i) => curState[i] && (Name !== curState[i].Name || Value !== curState[i].Value))
);

console.log(res);
```

You could also use `JSON.stringifiy()` on your `curState` so you can compare string versions of `VariationAttributes` against the string version of the VariationAttributes property:

```js
const arr = [{ "ASIN": "BCXXXXX1", "VariationAttributes": [{ "Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Left Hand" }, { "Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel" } ] }, { "ASIN": "BCXXXXX2", "VariationAttributes": [{ "Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Right Hand" }, { "Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel" } ] } ];
const curState = [{ "Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Left Hand" }, { "Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel" } ];

const strCurState = JSON.stringify(curState);
const res = arr.filter(
  obj => strCurState !== JSON.stringify(obj.VariationAttributes)
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = [{ "ASIN": "BCXXXXX1", "VariationAttributes": [{ "Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Left Hand" }, { "Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel" }] },{"ASIN":"BCXXXXX2", "VariationAttributes": [{   "Name": "hand_orientation","Value": "Right Hand"}, {"Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel"}]}];
var curState = [{"Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Left Hand"},{"Name":"shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel"}];

var finalResult = obj.filter(parentObj => {
    return JSON.stringify(parentObj.VariationAttributes) === JSON.stringify(curState);
});
console.log(finalResult)
```

The variable `finalResult` will have the filtered array.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this.

```js
var obj=[{ "ASIN": "BCXXXXX1", "VariationAttributes": [{ "Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Left Hand" }, { "Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel" }] },{"ASIN":"BCXXXXX2", "VariationAttributes": [{   "Name": "hand_orientation","Value": "Right Hand"}, {"Name": "shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel"}]}];
var curState=[{"Name": "hand_orientation", "Value": "Left Hand"},{"Name":"shaft_material_type", "Value": "KBS Max 90 Steel"}];

//var result = obj.map(m=>m.VariationAttributes).filter(search, curState);

var result = obj.filter(item => {
  return item.VariationAttributes.every(attr => {
    return curState.find(state => attr.Name === state.Name && attr.Value === state.Value);
  })
});

console.log(result);

function search(item){
  return Object.keys(this).some((key) => item[key] === this[key]);
}
//console.log(obj)
```